# Error:origin must be supplied How to solve this?

Tags: r, date, shiny, rstudio

```
date=seq(as.Date('2000-1-3'),length.out=6486,by=1)

library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("zoom", height = "350px"),
  plotOutput("overall", height = "150px",
             brush =  brushOpts(id = "brush", direction = "x")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  data=data.frame(
    date=date,
    ucl2=ucl2,
    ucl1=ucl1,
    price=price,
    lcl1=lcl1,
    lcl2=lcl2
  ) 


  p <- ggplot(data,aes(x=date))+
    geom_line(aes(y=ucl2),colour="blue")+
    geom_line(aes(y=lcl2),colour="blue")+
    geom_line(aes(y=price),colour="red")+
    geom_line(aes(y=ucl1),colour="green")+
    geom_line(aes(y=lcl1),colour="green")+
    ggtitle("7 days") + 
    xlab("ma of 7 days") +
    ylab("standard deviation")


  output$zoom <- renderPlot({
    if (!is.null(input$brush)) {
      p <- p +xlim(input$brush$xmin, input$brush$xmax)
    }
    p
  })

  output$overall <- renderPlot(p)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
Warning: Error in as.Date.numeric: 'origin' must be supplied
```

I have obtained the graph I wanted by these commands in shiny but zoom in function is not working ,when I select data to zoom in it shows error.
Error:origin must be supplied
How to solve this problem??

Comment: what is `x = date`. do you mean `x = Date.Time`?

Comment: date=seq(as.Date('2000-1-3'),length.out=6486,by=1)
@MichaelChirico x=date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  output$zoom <- renderPlot({
    if (!is.null(input$brush)) {
      p <- p + xlim(as.Date("1970-01-01") + input$brush$xmin, as.Date("1970-01-01") + input$brush$xmax)
    }
    p
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works but it shows this error whenever i zoom in                                           Warning: Removed 6129 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
Warning: Removed 6129 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
Warning: Removed 6129 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
Warning: Removed 4986 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
Warning: Removed 4986 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
Warning: Removed 4986 rows containing missing values (geom_path).

Comment: This is not an error, it is a warning, is the result correct?